# Is it called iPhone "X" or iPhone 10?

Tags: iphone

Going with Apple's history it was OS X (standing for OS 10) in older versions of Apple's operating system.

So with the new iPhone should I be calling iPhone "X" or iPhone 10?

What did they use in the announcements?

Comment: For reference https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/whats-the-proper-way-to-pronounce-mac-os-x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device is called **iPhone X, pronounced iPhone 10**.

The pronunciation follows on from (Mac) OS X being pronounced 10. In the special event, the announcement called the device out loud as ‘iPhone 10’. This is continued in the Apple video ‘[Introducing iPhone X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4wEI5zhHB0&t=15s)’.

[image]

This screenshot is showing the YouTube generated subtitles, as the manually written subtitles print ‘iPhone X’, which is what it's called but not how it's pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

its called the iphone 10 but they use x as roman numerals

Comment: You have no references and don't add any new information really.

Comment: @William that's called logic

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  Avoid an answer that simply restates an existing answer.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: @StrawHara it is not logical that Apple went 7,8,X.  Logically there should be a 9 which I think presents why people are confused.